# Troubles with DDEV and Elasticsearch connector in Drupal

Tags: elasticsearch, docker-compose, drupal-8, ddev

I'm facing some troubles with the integration  [search_api](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api) + Elasticsearch.

Actually, the whole environment is based on DDEV.

> docker-compose.elasticsearch.yaml

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  elasticsearch:
    container_name: ddev-${DDEV_SITENAME}-elasticsearch
    hostname: ${DDEV_SITENAME}-elasticsearch
    image: elasticsearch:7.5.2
    ports:
      - "9200"
      - "9300"
    environment:
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=$DDEV_HOSTNAME
      - HTTP_EXPOSE=9200
      - node.max_local_storage_nodes=3
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - TAKE_FILE_OWNERSHIP="true"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    labels:
      com.ddev.site-name: ${DDEV_SITENAME}
      com.ddev.approot: $DDEV_APPROOT
    volumes:
      - elasticsearch:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      - ".:/mnt/ddev_config"
  web:
    links:
      - elasticsearch:elasticsearch

volumes:
  elasticsearch:
    name: "${DDEV_SITENAME}-elasticsearch"
```

So, based on the Lullabot tutorial, in the last part about configuring the Elasticsearch connector, this one cannot reach out the connection neither  with the URL `http://NAME_PROJECT.ddev.site:9200` or `localhost:9200`

What else is missing or what I'm doing wrong?

BTW, the logs don't show anything unusual.

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
{"type": "deprecation", "timestamp": "2020-03-06T21:13:28,416Z", "level": "WARN", "component": "o.e.d.c.s.Settings", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "oneworkplace-elasticsearch", "message": "[node.max_local_storage_nodes] setting was deprecated in Elasticsearch and will be removed in a future release! See the breaking changes documentation for the next major version." }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-03-06T21:13:30,089Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.e.NodeEnvironment", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "oneworkplace-elasticsearch", "message": "using [1] data paths, mounts [[/usr/share/elasticsearch/data (/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root)]], net usable_space [388.3gb], net total_space [455.7gb], types [ext4]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-03-06T21:13:30,090Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.e.NodeEnvironment", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "oneworkplace-elasticsearch", "message": "heap size [494.9mb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-03-06T21:13:30,108Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.n.Node", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "oneworkplace-elasticsearch", "message": "node name [oneworkplace-elasticsearch], node ID [N2jmtxZnSlujZeBGQauZCw], cluster name [docker-cluster]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-03-06T21:13:30,109Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.n.Node", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "oneworkplace-elasticsearch", "message": "version[7.5.2], pid[1], build[default/docker/8bec50e1e0ad29dad5653712cf3bb580cd1afcdf/2020-01-15T12:11:52.313576Z], OS[Linux/5.3.0-40-generic/amd64], JVM[AdoptOpenJDK/OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM/13.0.1/13.0.1+9]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-03-06T21:13:30,110Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.n.Node", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "oneworkplace-elasticsearch", "message": "JVM home [/usr/share/elasticsearch/jdk]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-03-06T21:13:30,110Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.n.Node", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "oneworkplace-elasticsearch", "message": "JVM arguments [-Des.networkaddress.cache.ttl=60, -Des.networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl=10, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -Xss1m, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djna.nosys=true, -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow, -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true, -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true, -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0, -Dio.netty.allocator.numDirectArenas=0, -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false, -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true, -Djava.locale.providers=COMPAT, -Xms1g, -Xmx1g, -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC, -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75, -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly, -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/elasticsearch-13619040628599288608, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -XX:HeapDumpPath=data, -XX:ErrorFile=logs/hs_err_pid%p.log, -Xlog:gc*,gc+age=trace,safepoint:file=logs/gc.log:utctime,pid,tags:filecount=32,filesize=64m, -Des.cgroups.hierarchy.override=/, -Xms512m, -Xmx512m, -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=268435456, -Des.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch, -Des.path.conf=/usr/share/elasticsearch/config, -Des.distribution.flavor=default, -Des.distribution.type=docker, -Des.bundled_jdk=true]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-03-06T21:13:34,397Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "oneworkplace-elasticsearch", "message": "loaded module [aggs-matrix-stats]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-03-06T21:13:34,398Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "oneworkplace-elasticsearch", "message": "loaded module [analysis-common]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-03-06T21:13:34,398Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "oneworkplace-elasticsearch", "message": "loaded module [flattened]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-03-06T21:13:34,399Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "oneworkplace-elasticsearch", "message": "loaded module [frozen-indices]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-03-06T21:13:34,399Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "oneworkplace-elasticsearch", "message": "loaded module [ingest-common]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-03-06T21:13:34,399Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "oneworkplace-elasticsearch", "message": "loaded module [ingest-geoip]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-03-06T21:13:34,400Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "oneworkplace-elasticsearch", "message": "loaded module [ingest-user-agent]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-03-06T21:13:34,400Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "oneworkplace-elasticsearch", "message": "loaded module [lang-expression]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-03-06T21:13:34,400Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "oneworkplace-elasticsearch", "message": "loaded module [lang-mustache]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-03-06T21:13:34,400Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "oneworkplace-elasticsearch", "message": "loaded module [lang-painless]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-03-06T21:13:34,401Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "oneworkplace-elasticsearch", "message": "loaded module [mapper-extras]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-03-06T21:13:34,401Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "oneworkplace-elasticsearch", "message": "loaded module [parent-join]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-03-06T21:13:34,401Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "oneworkplace-elasticsearch", "message": "loaded module [percolator]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-03-06T21:13:34,401Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "oneworkplace-elasticsearch", "message": "loaded module [rank-eval]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-03-06T21:13:34,402Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "oneworkplace-elasticsearch", "message": "loaded module [reindex]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-03-06T21:13:34,402Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "oneworkplace-elasticsearch", "message": "loaded module [repository-url]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-03-06T21:13:34,402Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "oneworkplace-elasticsearch", "message": "loaded module [search-business-rules]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-03-06T21:13:34,403Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "oneworkplace-elasticsearch", "message": "loaded module [spatial]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-03-06T21:13:34,403Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "oneworkplace-elasticsearch", "message": "loaded module [transform]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-03-06T21:13:34,403Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "oneworkplace-elasticsearch", "message": "loaded module [transport-netty4]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-03-06T21:13:34,403Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "oneworkplace-elasticsearch", "message": "loaded module [vectors]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-03-06T21:13:34,404Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "oneworkplace-elasticsearch", "message": "loaded module [x-pack-analytics]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-03-06T21:13:34,404Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "oneworkplace-elasticsearch", "message": "loaded module [x-pack-ccr]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-03-06T21:13:34,404Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "oneworkplace-elasticsearch", "message": "loaded module [x-pack-core]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-03-06T21:13:34,404Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "oneworkplace-elasticsearch", "message": "loaded module [x-pack-deprecation]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-03-06T21:13:34,404Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "oneworkplace-elasticsearch", "message": "loaded module [x-pack-enrich]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-03-06T21:13:34,405Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "oneworkplace-elasticsearch", "message": "loaded module [x-pack-graph]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-03-06T21:13:34,405Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "oneworkplace-elasticsearch", "message": "loaded module [x-pack-ilm]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-03-06T21:13:34,405Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "oneworkplace-elasticsearch", "message": "loaded module [x-pack-logstash]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-03-06T21:13:34,405Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "oneworkplace-elasticsearch", "message": "loaded module [x-pack-ml]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-03-06T21:13:34,405Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "oneworkplace-elasticsearch", "message": "loaded module [x-pack-monitoring]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-03-06T21:13:34,406Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "oneworkplace-elasticsearch", "message": "loaded module [x-pack-rollup]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-03-06T21:13:34,406Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "oneworkplace-elasticsearch", "message": "loaded module [x-pack-security]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-03-06T21:13:34,406Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "oneworkplace-elasticsearch", "message": "loaded module [x-pack-sql]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-03-06T21:13:34,406Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "oneworkplace-elasticsearch", "message": "loaded module [x-pack-voting-only-node]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-03-06T21:13:34,407Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "oneworkplace-elasticsearch", "message": "loaded module [x-pack-watcher]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-03-06T21:13:34,407Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "oneworkplace-elasticsearch", "message": "no plugins loaded" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-03-06T21:13:43,853Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.x.m.p.l.CppLogMessageHandler", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "oneworkplace-elasticsearch", "message": "[controller/109] [Main.cc@110] controller (64 bit): Version 7.5.2 (Build 68f6981dfb8e2d) Copyright (c) 2020 Elasticsearch BV" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-03-06T21:13:44,812Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.d.DiscoveryModule", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "oneworkplace-elasticsearch", "message": "using discovery type [single-node] and seed hosts providers [settings]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-03-06T21:13:45,991Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.n.Node", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "oneworkplace-elasticsearch", "message": "initialized" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-03-06T21:13:45,992Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.n.Node", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "oneworkplace-elasticsearch", "message": "starting ..." }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-03-06T21:13:46,173Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.t.TransportService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "oneworkplace-elasticsearch", "message": "publish_address {172.18.0.4:9300}, bound_addresses {0.0.0.0:9300}" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-03-06T21:13:46,523Z", "level": "WARN", "component": "o.e.b.BootstrapChecks", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "oneworkplace-elasticsearch", "message": "max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-03-06T21:13:46,524Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.c.c.Coordinator", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "oneworkplace-elasticsearch", "message": "cluster UUID [1P_uM4H5SS6LPFQo-hFcnQ]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-03-06T21:13:46,693Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.c.s.MasterService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "oneworkplace-elasticsearch", "message": "elected-as-master ([1] nodes joined)[{oneworkplace-elasticsearch}{N2jmtxZnSlujZeBGQauZCw}{crTGNgbTTtSHBFyMjL5Cag}{172.18.0.4}{172.18.0.4:9300}{dilm}{ml.machine_memory=12424024064, xpack.installed=true, ml.max_open_jobs=20} elect leader, _BECOME_MASTER_TASK_, _FINISH_ELECTION_], term: 17, version: 91, delta: master node changed {previous [], current [{oneworkplace-elasticsearch}{N2jmtxZnSlujZeBGQauZCw}{crTGNgbTTtSHBFyMjL5Cag}{172.18.0.4}{172.18.0.4:9300}{dilm}{ml.machine_memory=12424024064, xpack.installed=true, ml.max_open_jobs=20}]}" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-03-06T21:13:46,965Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.c.s.ClusterApplierService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "oneworkplace-elasticsearch", "message": "master node changed {previous [], current [{oneworkplace-elasticsearch}{N2jmtxZnSlujZeBGQauZCw}{crTGNgbTTtSHBFyMjL5Cag}{172.18.0.4}{172.18.0.4:9300}{dilm}{ml.machine_memory=12424024064, xpack.installed=true, ml.max_open_jobs=20}]}, term: 17, version: 91, reason: Publication{term=17, version=91}" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-03-06T21:13:47,088Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.h.AbstractHttpServerTransport", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "oneworkplace-elasticsearch", "message": "publish_address {172.18.0.4:9200}, bound_addresses {0.0.0.0:9200}", "cluster.uuid": "1P_uM4H5SS6LPFQo-hFcnQ", "node.id": "N2jmtxZnSlujZeBGQauZCw"  }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-03-06T21:13:47,089Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.n.Node", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "oneworkplace-elasticsearch", "message": "started", "cluster.uuid": "1P_uM4H5SS6LPFQo-hFcnQ", "node.id": "N2jmtxZnSlujZeBGQauZCw"  }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-03-06T21:13:48,169Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.l.LicenseService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "oneworkplace-elasticsearch", "message": "license [3dd0f2f6-a0e6-4ba1-a801-748d8517434a] mode [basic] - valid", "cluster.uuid": "1P_uM4H5SS6LPFQo-hFcnQ", "node.id": "N2jmtxZnSlujZeBGQauZCw"  }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-03-06T21:13:48,192Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.g.GatewayService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "oneworkplace-elasticsearch", "message": "recovered [1] indices into cluster_state", "cluster.uuid": "1P_uM4H5SS6LPFQo-hFcnQ", "node.id": "N2jmtxZnSlujZeBGQauZCw"  }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-03-06T21:13:50,166Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.c.r.a.AllocationService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "oneworkplace-elasticsearch", "message": "Cluster health status changed from [RED] to [YELLOW] (reason: [shards started [[elasticsearch_index_db_elastic_index][1]]]).", "cluster.uuid": "1P_uM4H5SS6LPFQo-hFcnQ", "node.id": "N2jmtxZnSlujZeBGQauZCw"  }
{"type": "deprecation", "timestamp": "2020-03-06T21:15:30,185Z", "level": "WARN", "component": "o.e.d.r.a.d.RestGetAction", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "oneworkplace-elasticsearch", "message": "[types removal] Specifying types in document get requests is deprecated, use the /{index}/_doc/{id} endpoint instead.", "cluster.uuid": "1P_uM4H5SS6LPFQo-hFcnQ", "node.id": "N2jmtxZnSlujZeBGQauZCw"  }
```

Comment: have you tried to curl the cluster health url?

Comment: The correct URL for the web container to reach the elasticsearch container is going to be http://elasticsearch:9200. Neither "localhost" (which would be the web container) nor "<project>.ddev.site:9200" is correct in this case, mostly because you didn't include in external_links `        external_links:
            - "ddev-router:${DDEV_HOSTNAME}"
`

Comment: thanks @rfay , this worked like charm

Comment: @AndresGuerrero can  you please share version of drupal, ES connector and search API versions I have issue in configuration of  ES cluster in ES if possible?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you were having was that you were thinking that "localhost" would be the right thing for the web container to use, but in fact, each container is a separate entity, and the elasticsearch server is running on the service/container/host named "elasticsearch" in your configuration, so that's what you'll want to use.

I think you also *could* have used the suggested `http://NAME_PROJECT.ddev.site:9200` had you included this in your docker-compose.elasticsearch.yaml, which makes access to NAME_PROJECZT.ddev.site go through ddev-router:

```
services:
    elasticsearch: 
        external_links: 
        - "ddev-router:${DDEV_HOSTNAME}"
```